Query to calculate the remaining units to the next day
Context: I have a table that has 3 columns: "day", "arrivals", "max_output_capacity".
The table is basically this:



day
arrivals
max_output_capacity




0
0
2


1
2
3


2
5
4


3
0
5


4
0
5


5
14
1


6
0
3



The arrivals are units (packages) that arrive to the shop each day. Those units need to be sent to destinations ideally that very same day.
Most of the time the maximum_output_capacity each day is enough to send all packages that same day, but sometimes the arrivals are larger than the maximum output capacity. When this happens, there is a remaining number of packages that needs to be sent the next day, or the day after (in case not everything gets sent that day) and so on, depending on how many units are still yet to be sent.
I want to calculate the remaining units on each day.
In an Excel spreadsheet, this is very easy to do. This remaining field is
remaining_next_day [ti] = max between [0] and [arrivals - max_output_capacity + remaining_next_day[t_i-1]]
(I took care of the exception at the first day)
This formula gives the following result:



day
arrivals
max_output_capacity
remaining_next_day




0
0
2
0


1
2
3
0


2
5
4
1


3
0
5
0


4
0
5
0


5
14
1
13


6
0
3
10



So, I need to populate that last column but with an SQL query.
I have tried everything, chatGPT, tutorials, LAG function, etc. No success so far, for the last 6 days.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.
I am using MS Access as my first option. But I could use SQLite as well.
This seems very simple, but the tricky part is the recursiveness IMHO.
My code to set this up is:
CREATE TABLE process_table(day, arrivals, max_output_capacity)
INSERT INTO process_table VALUES ('0', 0, 2), ('1', 2, 3), ('2', 5, 4), ('3', 0, 5), ('4', 0, 5), ('5', 14, 1), ('6', 0, 3)
Cheers
I tried different queries, for example:
WITH AccumulatedRemaining AS (
    SELECT 
        day,
        arrivals,
        max_output_capacity,
        IIf(
            arrivals > max_output_capacity,
            arrivals - max_output_capacity,
            0
        ) AS current_day_remaining,
        IIf(
            arrivals > max_output_capacity,
            arrivals - max_output_capacity,
            0
        ) AS acumulated_remaining
    FROM process_table
    ORDER BY day
),
NextDayRemaining AS (
    SELECT 
        r1.day,
        r1.arrivals,
        r1.max_output_capacity,
        r1.current_day_remaining,
        IIf(
            r1.acumulated_remaining + r2.current_day_remaining > r1.max_output_capacity,
            r1.acumulated_remaining + r2.current_day_remaining - r1.max_output_capacity,
            0
        ) AS remaining_next_day
    FROM AccumulatedRemaining AS r1
    LEFT JOIN AccumulatedRemaining AS r2 ON r2.day = r1.day + 1
)
SELECT 
    day,
    arrivals,
    max_output_capacity,
    current_day_remaining,
    remaining_next_day
FROM NextDayRemaining
ORDER BY day;


Rewritten according to the comment:-

....  that initial scenario, but it fails in others: ....

Perhaps consider the following that uses a TRIGGER to maintain the remaining_next_day (added as a new column):-
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS process_table;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS process_table(day, arrivals, max_output_capacity, remaining INTEGER DEFAULT 0);
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS pt_insert_trigger 
AFTER INSERT ON process_table
WHEN 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE process_table SET remaining = 
        max(
        0,
        new.arrivals +
        coalesce((SELECT remaining FROM process_table WHERE day < new.day ORDER BY day DESC LIMIT 1),0)
        - new.max_output_capacity) WHERE rowid = new.rowid;
END;
INSERT INTO process_table (day,arrivals,max_output_capacity) VALUES ('0', 0, 2), ('1', 2, 3), ('2', 5, 4), ('3', 0, 5), ('4', 0, 5), ('5', 14, 1), ('6', 0, 3);
SELECT * FROM process_table;
DELETE FROM process_table;
INSERT INTO process_table (day,arrivals,max_output_capacity) VALUES ('0', 2, 1), ('1', 0, 1), ('2', 2, 1), ('3', 2, 1), ('4', 2, 1), ('5', 2, 1), ('6', 2, 1);
SELECT * FROM process_table;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS process_table;


note the additional column, and the underlying changes

Which results in:-


for the data as per the question

and :-

for the data as per the comment

Hey, thanks!!,
I tried that and it does solve that initial scenario, but it fails in others: For example, when you try this setup:
INSERT INTO process_table VALUES ('0', 2, 1), ('1', 0, 1), ('2', 2, 1), ('3', 2, 1), ('4', 2, 1), ('5', 2, 1), ('6', 2, 1);
the expected correct remaining_next_day is: 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. But the solution you created shows this: 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2.
The problem is a recursive mess. Thanks anyway!

@FelipeBrunet perhaps consider an alternative approach via a TRIGGER (answer updated accordingly)
